# Java applet won't connect to host through socket

Tags: java, sockets, applet, ip

I have an interesting predicament... I have a java applet that will connect to its host(a java application) through a socket by calling `getCodeBase().getHost()`. I have a web-server set up using IIS and a dynamic dns setup using no-ip, and when I open the applet through my external IP it will create a socket connection to the host on port 44444 but using the ip, matrix159.no-ip.biz which is the dynamic host name, causes the socket to not connect. Sorry if this question is not worded properly, but I have searched and can't find any answers!

```
 private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    try 
    {

        System.out.println(getCodeBase().toString() + " " + "This is codebase");
        String host = getCodeBase().getHost();
        System.out.println(host);
        socket = new Socket(getCodeBase().getHost(), 44444);
        System.out.println("Socket opened");
        if(host == null)System.out.println("Host was null");
        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeUTF(buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand());
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Here is the error it produced.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-27" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 50.124.10.35:44444 connect,resolve)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:376)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2SecurityManager.checkPermission(Applet2SecurityManager.java:236)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1034)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2SecurityManager.checkConnect(Applet2SecurityManager.java:568)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:522)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:476)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:373)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:187)
at myapplet.Main$3.run(Main.java:185)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: Provide an error message.

Comment: I provided the code where I know the applet is getting stuck at because when I click the submitButton it will freeze and become unresponsive, and the Java Console for the applet doesn't provide any errors since it is stuck in a frozen state trying to connect.

Comment: Well you shouldn't perform blocking operations such as network operations in the AWT event thread for a start. That explains the freeze. Fix that and then post the exception you get.

Comment: And exception will happen after timeout. Be patient and wait 10 minutes or so :)

Comment: Ok I will, should I use a normal Thread or a Swing Worker?